The AnimatePresence of framer-motion doesn't work as expected
The AnimatePresence component of framer-motion doesn't work as expected.
I have the following code:
import { useState } from "react";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

export default function App() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="max-w-sm mx-auto">
      <button onClick={() => setA((a) => !a)}>Button</button>
      <AnimatePresence>
        {a ? (
          <motion.div
            key="a"
            initial={{ x: -100, opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
            exit={{ x: -100, opacity: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 2 }}
          >
            A
          </motion.div>
        ) : (
          <motion.div
            key="b"
            initial={{ x: 100, opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
            exit={{ x: 100, opacity: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 2 }}
          >
            B
          </motion.div>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
  );
}

When I click the button several times both components appear showing A and B. That doesn't make sense because only one component should appear.

I wasn't able to find the 'why' but I could fix it. Can you try this? Whenever 'AnimatePresence' doesn't work as I expected, I usually divide it into multiple AnimatePresence.
import { useState } from 'react';
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';

export default function Test() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="max-w-sm mx-auto">
      <button onClick={() => setA((a) => !a)}>Button</button>

      {a && (
        <AnimatePresence>
          <motion.div
            key="a"
            initial={{ x: -100, opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
            exit={{ x: -100, opacity: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 2 }}
          >
            A
          </motion.div>
        </AnimatePresence>
      )}

      {!a && (
        <AnimatePresence>
          <motion.div
            key="b"
            initial={{ x: 100, opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ x: 0, opacity: 1 }}
            exit={{ x: 100, opacity: 0 }}
            transition={{ duration: 2 }}
          >
            B
          </motion.div>
        </AnimatePresence>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

